# Tableview last cell is not visible using scrollview iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have structure of file as : View -> ScrollView -> TableView.
Now the content of tableView is dynamically determined. If the content is quite large then last record of table is not visible. I tried setting following code :

```
 self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0,568.0);

[self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x, 0)
                         animated:YES];
```

but created problem in landscape mode. The content of table is getting scrolled to much bottom. If size of ScrollBar that appears while scrolling is decreased will it work?

Any other fix for this problem?

[image]

Comment: Check auto layout settings in storyboard/xibs too... maybe there's something wrong there

Comment: This is according to Apple.    " You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled."

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is kind of dirty, lol. Use -

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 120, 0); //values passed are - top, left, bottom, right
```

Pass bottom offset as per your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Your `tableView` height is supposed to be, `ScreeHeight-NavBarHeight`. In your case, it looks like you `tableView` is taller than the visible screen height available to it.

As a quick fix, try following but ideally you need to use constraints so it automatically sized according to the available screen height.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    CGFloat navbarHeight = 44; //In iOS7, this is supposed to be 64 but you should dynamically calculate it or better use constraints
    CGRect tempFrame = self.view.frame;
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tempFrame.origin.x, tempFrame.origin.y, tempFrame.size.width, tempFrame.size.height - navbarHeight);
}
```

NOTE: This code needs to go to your `UITableViewController` sub class

Answer (score 0):

You have to take into consideration table's view row height and number of row while setting scrollview's contentSize. For instance, if your tableview's height is 200 and the tableview contains 3 rows, your content size's height should be set as follows:-

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, (200 * 3));
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x, 0)
                     animated:YES];
```

Comment: This one creating problem in case of Landscape-Orientation. The Header Section goes much above and the tableView is displayed half. Tried all other stuffs but didn't get any break-through...